# Microsoft Teams in iframe

Tags: iframe, requestly, cors

I've been able to push Outlook and the Office 365 home page into an iframe for our internal use by removing x-frame headers and content security policy, but Microsoft Teams seems to have an additional redirect that stops the site from loading in an iframe. Is it possible to work around that kind of redirect, and if so, how?

Comment: There could be multiple ways of bursting out of Iframe. Can you please share a sample Microsoft Teams link. You need to reverse engineer the impl of iframe bursting my MS team page and then handle that in Requestly accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @sachinjain024. A sample Teams link looks like this: https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/19:00ca88ee-21da-4aa2-b8b5-b9c3e49e1819_4f743e5c-c91b-4e1f-bee1-0a280cc78979@unq.gbl.spaces?messageId=1576019425379&ctx=chat

Comment: We tried multiple times but we couldn't open MS teams at our side. It prompts login and we don't have a MS teams account. Do you think if we are able to open MS teams signin page in Iframe, that should help?

Comment: @sachinjain024: I tried to put the signin page in an Iframe, but that refused to connect as well.
Something about that particular redirect (as was the case with Gmail when I tried to Iframe it a couple years ago) hangs up and won't allow me through.